# How to display a bar which shows a certain percent?

Tags: jquery, graphics

I have a set of articles with values of a field ranging from 0 to 10. I want to display these values graphically with a bar. E. g. if a value of that field in an article is 5.4, that's 54% and a bar with 54% of the surface in another color should be displayed. I found jQuery UI Progressbar plugin (http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar), but I'm not sure if it's possible to use it to display fixed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI's progressbar is very easy to use and does static values.

I've been using that on one of my sites and set various colors based on the percentage I set in the progressbar.

To use it is very simple:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar({value: 37});
```

That will display a progressbar about 1/3rd filled (give or take a bit). Then you can style it to any width you need it.

If you want to change the value after the bar has been set, you can do that with the setter option:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 90);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess if I want to resize it dinamically, instead of "37" I'd use div value (e. g. "$('#progressbar').progressbar({value: #myvalue});
")?

Comment: That sounds like you would need this: `$('#progressbar').progressbar({value: $('myvalue').val()});` and yes, it would work.

Comment: Just updated my answer to include setting the value after the progressbar has been created

Comment: I'm trying to make it work on Js Fiddle, but without success (http://jsfiddle.net/kLhFR/1). I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: I can't get it to work in jsfiddle at the moment either. I know it does work because I'm looking at the page on my site containing the progress bars. So give it a try on a page and see if you get better results than jsfiddle.

Comment: I have suceeded to make ti work with fixed values, but it doesn't display a bar with flexible values. I have div id called "myvalue" and a certain number in it. The code for progressbar is, as you suggested, `$('#progressbar').progressbar({value: $('#myvalue').val()});`

Comment: If you want to change the value after the bar is loaded, you have to use the setter (see the last example in my post above).